Will these stripes be very visible if I apply finish to the hardwood floors without doing more sanding?
I recently decided to refinish the hardwood floors on the second story of my home.  To do this, I rented a drum sander from a local rental facility, and ran it over the floors up through the procession of grits.  The results can be seen at the bottom of the post (note: the floors pictured are not 100% finished with sanding yet, particularly around the edges).  I have not yet applied any finish.  I noticed after looking at the floors in certain lighting, that I can see small lines that line up with where I used the drum sander's lever to drop the drum into contact with the floor.  Will these be extremely obvious and look bad if I apply finish to the floor in its current state? If so, what should I do to minimize the appearance of these depressions?  I tried wiping a damp towel across the floor to see what it would look like, but I still would like some advice.  Thanks.





In my limited experience with finishing wood pieces, putting a stain or varnish will increase the contrast, and will make it look more noticeable.

I agree, @Matthew. Post an answer.

Welcome, ho88it. Please take the [tour].

Thanks... so, since the drum sander created these ripples, is there a different tool you would advise I use to get them out?

As you can see, you are not done with sanding.
Using Stain or Varnish will no cover but do the opposite. It will enhance the differences. That means that the natural differences in the wood will be enhanced.

I see.  So what type of sander would you recommend I use?  The drum sander I rented is what caused these ripples.  Is there a type of sander that I best for removing these slight ripples?

@ho88it drum sander are tricky to use, basically never stop moving and use same speed of movement, you can try hand held sanders for small surfaces, disk or band

ok, thanks.  I've had some people recommend I get an orbital sander to smooth things out, but I've also heard that can create cross-grain scratches.  And, I know there are buffers that I could get as well.  What are your thoughts on these?

Update: I got a U-Sand orbital sander and that did the trick!  Those grooves are gone now.

@ho88it well done
